# PyPDF extract text from highlight annonations coordinates

Tags: python, pypdf

I want to extract the Text from Highlight Annotations.

PyPDF should be able to do this.
They provide an example on how to get the coordinates for the Highlights:
https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/reading-pdf-annotations.html#highlights

After I have the coordinates, I understand I should use [extract_text()](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/extract-text.html?highlight=extract_text#using-a-visitor) with  [visitor_text()](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/PageObject.html?highlight=visitor_text#pypdf._page.PageObject.extract_text)

But the use of this function is very confusing to me and I can't seem to wrap my head around the 2 examples provided..

Anybody so kind to show me the link between following code examples:

```
from pypdf import PdfReader
    
reader = PdfReader("commented.pdf")
for page in reader.pages:
    if "/Annots" in page:
        for annot in page["/Annots"]:
            subtype = annot.get_object()["/Subtype"]
            if subtype == "/Highlight":
                coords = annot.get_object()["/QuadPoints"]
                x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4 = coords
                # print(coords)
                # [51.10668, 704.2371, 99.92829, 704.2371, 51.10668, 689.7126, 99.92829, 689.7126]
                
                # page.extract_text(visitor_text=visitor_body)
                # ??? how to pass these coordinates
```

```
parts = []
def visitor_body(text, cm, tm, font_dict, font_size):
    # ??? tm: Text Matrix
    parts.append(text)
...
text_body = "".join(parts)
print(text_body)
```

from the manual:

> **extract_text**(
> <strike>*args: Any,</strike>
> <strike>Tj_sep: Optional[str] = None,</strike>
> <strike>TJ_sep: Optional[str] = None,</strike>
> <strike>orientations: Union[int, Tuple[int, ...]] = (0, 90, 180, 270),</strike>
> <strike>space_width: float = 200.0,</strike>
> <strike>visitor_operand_before: Optional[Callable[[Any, Any, Any, Any], None]] = None,</strike>
> <strike>visitor_operand_after: Optional[Callable[[Any, Any, Any, Any], None]]= None,</strike>
> **visitor_text**: Optional[Callable[[Any, Any, Any, Any, Any], None]] = None
> ) → str
>
> Locate all text drawing commands, in the order they are provided in the content stream, and extract the text.
> Additionally you can provide visitor-methods to get informed on all operations and all text-objects.
>
> *Parameters*
> **visitor_text** – function to be called when extracting some text at some position.
> It has five arguments: text, current transformation matrix, **text matrix**, font-dictionary and font-size.
>
> *Returns*
> The extracted text

Comment: "I want to extract the Text from Highlight Annotations.": Do you want to extract the text attribute of he annotation or do you want to extract the text that is highlighted?